# Live streaming with Twitter and RSS information

Tags: video, streaming, live

In two weeks, we have a live event for 7 days. Last year we bought Wirecast, but it looks like it has just a few features. They now integrated Twitter, but it's just weird how it's all made.

We have a lot of experience in RSS, JSON, and XML, and we really want to put it at use for this livestream event.

What we want to do is to create 2 separate RSS files (or JSON, XML). 1 for latest tweets and 1 for current audio track.

Next we want to integrate those RSS files in our video stream. Twitter in some sort of newsticker and the current track every 3 minutes or something.

Our problem, what software do we use? Wirecast looks like it isn't capable to handle our needs. Same for Xsplit and Media Encoder of course. Boinx looks like it has some features, but it's too expensive to just buy without knowledge.

Does anybody have an idea for what software to use?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into [Camtwiststudio](http://camtwiststudio.com) for the mac. I work with [Desert Bus for Hope](http://desertbus.org) doing a weeklong stream as well and we use it for just the sort of thing you're talking about.

Camtwist has built-in plugins for both Twitter and RSS, and can leverage quartz composer to make more complicated overlays.

It outputs a video feed for other Mac OS X applications to see it like a QuickTime video source, so you can use wireless or Flash Media Live encoder to do the actual compression and streaming.

Answer (score 0):

This could probably be done using Open Broadcast Software and writing your own plugin for it, but the details of how to do that is more of a programing question than a video production question.

I honestly don't think you are going to find anything out of the box that handles your specific needs.  You are going to have to do some development work to get it up and running I think.